# Delay fixed window from triggering for several minutes

Tags: apache-beam

Using Fixed Windows in Apache Beam. The watermark is set by the event time.

Some data may arrive out of order and cause the window to close.

How can a trigger be defined in Java to occur say 2 minutes after the last data was seen?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entire clear what behavior you expect. One question is what do you expect to happen if the data arrives within the two minutes? Do you want to restart the two minutes interval, don't restart it, re-emit the data or not?

Looks like the trigger you are trying to describe is something along these lines:

- wait until the watermark passed the end of window, in event time;
- wait for additional 2 minutes in processing time;
- emit the data;

If in step 2 it was event time, i.e. you wanted to re-emit the window if a late element arrives that fits within `window + 2min`, then you could use [`withAllowedLateness()`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.html#withAllowedLateness-org.joda.time.Duration-). Though it sounds different from what you want, because it can keep re-emitting the window contents every time a matching late element arrives.

With processing-time in step 2 this is not possible in general with basic triggers that are available in Beam. You can probably achieve a behavior you want if you [manually manage state and timers in your own `ParDo`](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html), e.g. you can watch for the incoming elements, keep track on them in the state, and then on timer emit what you want. This can become very complicated and might still be not flexible enough for your specific use case.

One of the major problems is that there is no good way to define processing time triggers in Beam in general. It would be complicated to define a general mechanism of working with timers in this manner. For example, when you want to express `"wait for 2 minutes"`, the framework needs to understand in relation to what these two minutes are, when to start the timer, so you need a mechanism to express that as well. And with composition, continuation and other complications this doesn't seem easy to reason about. So it's not in the framework in this general form.

In order to implement only the `"wait for 2 minutes after the last element was seen in the window"`, the framework has to watch for it and set the timer. Technically it is possible to do something like this but doesn't seem like anyone has done it yet.

There seems to be [only one](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/AfterProcessingTime.html) meaningful processing time trigger available in Beam but it's not generic enough and doesn't do what you want. You can look at composite triggers like [`AfterFirst`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/AfterFirst.html) or [`AfterAll`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/AfterAll.html) but they likely won't help you without a better general processing time trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found Beam to be a bit more complicated than I was hoping and pursued Apache Kafka instead.  I'll post my solution in Kafka

Answer (score 0):

I decided against using Beam and implemented the solution in Kafka Streams.

I basically grouped by, then used fixed windows and the aggregated the result.
The "grace" on the window allows data to arrive late.

```java
KGroupedStream<Long, OxyStreamItem> grouped = input.groupByKey();

TimeWindowedKStream<Long, OxyStreamItem> windowed = 
  grouped.windowedBy(
    TimeWindows.of(WIN_SIZE)
            .advanceBy(WIN_SIZE)
            .grace(Duration.ofSeconds(5L)));

return windowed
         .aggregate(
            makeInitializer(),
            makeAggregator(),
            Materialized
              .<Long, Aggregate, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("tmp")
              .withValueSerde(new AggregateSerde()))
         .suppress(
            Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
         .toStream()
         .map(calculateAvg());
```

Comment: Can you update your solution to point out that this is Kafka, so that future readers don't attempt to run this example with Beam?